# Read XML file data in flex3 using Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I am new in Flex action script ( I am using Flash Builder4).
I have a xml file book.xml and a image folder containing images according to the book.xml. I have to read book.xml file and show thumbnails and when click on thumb it should show its full size image("_T" indicates thumb image).How can I do this in easy steps.
Thanks in advance..

book.xml looks like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>

```
<pages>
    <page number="001">
        <fiwimage>/images/IT_P001.png</fiwimage>
        <thumbimage>/images/IT_P001_T.png</thumbimage>
    </page>
    <page number="002">
        <fiwimage>/images/IT_P002.png</fiwimage>
        <thumbimage>/images/IT_P002_T.png</thumbimage>
    </page>
    <page number="003">
        <fiwimage>/images/IT_P003.png</fiwimage>
        <thumbimage>/images/IT_P003_T.png</thumbimage>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks RIAstar for quick response..
I googled for this and found somthing on a link:[link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/03/displaying-images-from-an-xml-file-using-the-repeater-component/)

Comment: I mean: do you have a specific issue? We are here to help you, not to write your code for you.

Comment: I want to read xml so that can get image source like "/images/IT_P003.png"

Comment: I have added a TileList in my main mxml file and given itemRenderer as:
 itemRenderer="CustomItemRenderer"
and CustomItemRenderer.mxml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/08/creating-a-simple-image-gallery-with-the-flex-tilelist-control/ -->
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
   horizontalAlign="center"
   verticalAlign="middle" height="600" >
 <mx:Image source="{data.@thumbnailImage}" />
 <mx:Label text="{data.@title}" />
</mx:VBox>
Here image source getting as attribute but I want it according my xml file. how to do it.Thanks

Comment: "data.@thumbimage" insted of "data.@thumbnailImage" in your itemrenderer.

Comment: Sorry its spelling mistake, but when I use @thumbimage, its used for attribute whereas I have to get node value not attribute value from xml file. How to do that.Thanks Mahesh Parate..Please can you help me more.

Comment: if you are working with attribute you have to use "@" otherwise you can use "." notation(Period) i.e .thumbimage